# Firebase Analytics UI changes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am a viewer of one firebase project and I am not authorized to display the same information via google analytics.

Although I would like to see a bar graph of user number by age-group(Demographics) like first attached picture which is quoted from https://applicaster.zendesk.com/hc/article_attachments/360000598223/mceclip7.png, I could only see a time series graph of user number plus some other ranking graph on "Analytics > Audiences" like second attached picture.

[graph example of user demographics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTFi5.png)

[current view which does not contain demographics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHrO6.jpg)

I think first attached graph was previously available on "Audiences" and now it's available only when I display it via Google analytics.

I am wondering whether this is due to firebase update.

I would appreciate it if anyone could answer to the above question.

I apologize my explanation might not be clear enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view changed for firebase and Google analytics both.

To get similar view as you want you can use [Google Analytics User Starter Bundle](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/gallery/#posts/search/%3F_.viewId%3DbENJATfQRzGVtZkEWSqd6A/)

Comment: Since I cannot login to Google Analytics of the project(property), I will send a request to get authorization of it.
Currently I can login to the firebase project, but cannot login to Google Analytics of the same.